# What's the difference between AWS S3 boto3 client's put_object and upload_file in terms of transferring media files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, command-line-interface, boto3

AWS transcription works when I transfer local media files using boto3 client's upload_file(), but fails with

```
'FailureReason': 'Invalid data in input media file'
```

every time I transfer the media files using the S3 client's put_object(). Same key, bucket, and filename parameters.

What's the cause of this? It took me forever to figure out since the error is not very descriptive.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code (including creation of the client/resource) so that we can try to reproduce? What sort of file is it (mp4)? Does it happen on _every_file of that type, or just one specific file?

Comment: The code for resource and client creation is standard from the documentation:
    boto3.client("s3"), and boto3.resource("s3"). 
I am using .wav files, but when transferred with put_object, the transcription job also threw an error for mp3's. Yes it fails on every file of wav and mp3 type.

Comment: Let's divide your situation into two steps: Upload and Transcribe. You are saying that using `upload_file()` and then transcribing works fully, is that correct? Then why are you wanting to use `put_object()` instead of `upload_file()`? If you use `put_object()` and then download the object from S3, does it play like the original .wav file? (This will check whether the upload is having the problem.)